# `devtools::install_git()` with stored git credentials

Tags: r, devtools

Currently using `install_git()` to install from a repo protected by Azure Active Directory results in an error:

```
> devtools::install_git("https://myteam.visualstudio.com/MyProject/_git/MyAwesomeRPackage")
Downloading git repo https://myteam.visualstudio.com/MyProject/_git/MyAwesomeRPackage
Installation failed: Error in 'git2r_clone': Unable to authenticate with supplied credentials
```

even though the AAD credentials are stored in the git  credential manager.  For example, calling this from the command line works just fine:

```
git clone https://myteam.visualstudio.com/MyProject/_git/MyAwesomeRPackage
```

is there any way to have R use the credentials from the git credential manager for this install?

Comment: Haven't tested it, but have you tried the `git` parameter, e.g., `git = "external"`?

Comment: @thc thanks for the suggestion.  Sadly it didn't help.

Comment: Turns out my devtools was out of date.  I re-installed the latest version of devtools from CRAN and everything works as expected **but it did require using the `git="external"` hint**.   @thc, if you provide that as an answer, i'll accept it.

Comment: Sweet, easy internet points :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `git` parameter, e.g., `git = "external"`.